# use php to read the txt file that keep on changing and present them in a table

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi to monitor a solar system. I have intercepted some sensors at the point that i want to get measurement and the reading will be printed into a text file on the desktop of raspberry pi. Now i have installed an Apache server and `php` lib on the Raspberry Pi and a file call `index.php` has been created and act as the homepage for my server. Now i want to present those value on that particular page. How should i write the code because i am really new to `php`.

Comment: What is format of text file that is being generated. How often the file is being updated by the sensors? Is it possible that you can encode the file contents and be able to redirect the output to php script. e.g. redirect the output to index.php. I can think of a setup where you encode the data in json and redirect to the php file. Inside the php file you will be able to read php://input . Please provide info on the asked points

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @vishwakarma09, hi, i plan to do the sensor measurement and write it  into the txt file for every 60 secs. now i am reading the voltage measured from the voltage sensor and write it into a file called  voltage-log.txt where the sequence is like:
<value>
<blank row>
<value>.

i dont really understand the 3rd question. issit u mean that can i directly sending the value into the index.php and overwrite the content inside.

Comment: Hi @AaronTzeng I have added an answer with sample scripts. These scripts you can extend as per your needs. To show data, you will need to write a page that will query the database for the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code to a file, overwriting the file every 60 seconds. In index.php, you can open that file for every 60 seconds (by adjusting the sleeptime). I have run this process side-by-side in two command terminals and they work. Refer to [image: this] image

Now, the code for index.php is as follows:

```
<?php 

while(1){
    $fp  = fopen('fifo', 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, 4096);
    echo "data received is " .  trim($data) . "\n";
    saveData($data);
    fclose($fp);
    sleep(2);
}   


/* function to save data to databse */
function saveData($data = null){

    //connect to database
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "csvdata") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $insertQuery = "insert into tblcsvdata values(NULL, '".$data."')";
    /*
        assuming that the table structure is 
        Id - null
        data - varchar
    */
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertQuery);
}
```

The code for write is as follows:

```
<?php 

while(1){
    file_put_contents('fifo', sha1(rand(1,1000)));
    sleep(2);
}
```

In place of writer, there will be your script which will write the voltage to file. In the index.php, I have also added the function saveData() which will save the voltage to database.

You should tune the sleep interval as per your needs (60 seconds).

Comment: i tried to paste that code into the index.php and my http://localhost become blank. issit because of i didnt set the msql databse's things?

Comment: yes, you need to create a database. You can use phpmyadmin to create database. Also, by default there is no error shown. You can try using these statements in the beginning of code: ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); You can read in comments the table structure.